# Replacement for TraceFilter in Azure.WebJobs 3.0+

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am upgrading from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 2.0.0 to 3.0.30. In our existing code, we have some custom code that uses the `TraceFilter` from the older SDK, which is no longer present.

Is there a way to port the following code relying on `JobHostConfiguration` and `TraceFilter` to the newer SDK?

In Program.Main():

```
// config was a JobHostConfiguration, which is not present in the newer SDK
config.Tracing.Tracers.Add(new TraceMonitor()
                .Filter(e => (e.Exception is FunctionInvocationException fie ? fie.InnerException : e.Exception)?.IsMonitored() ?? false, "Exception Handler")
                .Subscribe(Process));
```

```
public void Process(TraceFilter filter)
{
   var events = filter.GetEvents().Where(e => e.Exception != null);
   foreach (var traceEvent in events) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- In Azure SDK 2.0 an instance of **JobHostConfiguration** is used to configure settings Like,  **Tracing**  and  **Timer**  Methods and then this configuration object is passed as a parameter in JobHost instance, JobHost is a runtime container to execute continuously and triggered WebJobs by calling RunAndBlock method of JobHost instance.

[image]

- In **SDK 3.0**,  **JobHostConfiguration** has been removed and in place of it, all configurations are configured by **HostBuilder**.
- The Host Builder is much like the latest ASP.Net Core. Firstly you need to create an instance of HostBuilder and configure it as ‘Development’ environment and then configure WebJobs by calling ConfigureWebJobs method.

In this method setup AddAzureStorageCoreServices (it will hook WebJobs to Azure storage Account) and AddTimers ( will let WebJobs to periodically trigger tasks defined in the project).